# Silverlight Panel OnChildAdded event?

Tags: silverlight, controls

I'm trying to derive from the Silverlight Panel control to add some custom logic whenever a control is added to the Panel.  I can't seem to find an "OnChildAdded" event (Or something similar) on the Children collection.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can tell when a child control is added to a Panel or do I have to write my own container control?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684197/silveright-uielementcollection-change-notifications/684961#684961) - unfortunately you can't get notification with the existing UIElementCollection Children property, but you could try a custom [implementation](http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/866/Silverlight-Getting-notified-upon-changes-to-a-Panel-rsquo-s-Children-of-type-UIElementCollection-property.aspx).